# Erro na inserção do banco Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string

Tags: php

Estou tentando inserir alguns dados em uma tabela utilizando PHP e está acontecendo alguns erros.

Está é a forma que estou usando para inserir:

```
$cnpj = "000001";
$sth = $lokos->prepare("INSERT INTO CLENTES (CNPJ) VALUES (?)"); 
$sth->bindParam(1, $cnpj, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->execute(); 
$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo $sth;
```

Estou tentando inserir dados na tabela `CLENTES` no campo CNPJ e está acontecendo esse erro:

```
( ! ) Catchable fatal error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string in C:\wamp\www\site\index.php on line 30
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0000  134952  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
```

O que eu posso fazer para arrumar isso?

Comment: Segundo o erro está dizendo que a função não conseguiu converter o valor para `string`, e se você trabalhasse com valores `int`? O nome da tabela realmente é `CLENTES`ou `CLIENTES`

Comment: Muita gente já deu respostas diferentes. Se manifeste informando se sua questão já foi resolvida ou não, para que possam lhe ajudar ou ficarem sabendo que já foi ajudado.  E clique no botão "aceitar como resposta" na resposta que lhe ajudou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sua lógica está errada...

```
$cnpj = "000001";
$sth = $lokos->prepare("INSERT INTO CLENTES (CNPJ) VALUES (?)"); 
$sth->bindParam(1, $cnpj, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->execute();
// Até aqui está mais ou menos certo 

// O comando fetch serve para consultas, ou seja, SELECTs - ESTÁ ERRADO
$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
// Você não pode imprimir um objeto com echo
echo $sth;
```

Faça da seguinte forma:

```
$cnpj = "000001";
$sth = $lokos->prepare("INSERT INTO CLENTES (CNPJ) VALUES (:cnpj)"); 
$sth->bindParam(':cnpj', $cnpj, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->execute();
```

Answer (score 5):

O problema é que você está tentando dar **echo $sth**...
Só que $sth não é do tipo string. Por isso o erro.

É só apagar o `echo $sth;` que o erro some.

Edit:
Tente fazer desta forma:

```
$cnpj = "000001";
$db = new PDO(
    "mysql:host=host.com.br; dbname=databaseName",
    "usuario",
    "senha"
);
$db->query("INSERT INTO CLENTES (
    CNPJ
)
VALUES (
    ?
); ");
$result = db->query("Select * From CLENTES")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: nao lek, isso não tem nada a ver, mesmo eu tirando esse echo coisa que eu ja fiz, ele não consegue inserir dados no campo informado

Comment: Olha, não estou dizendo que vai funcionar...
Esse `echo $sth;` está incorreto. Mesmo que removendo o mesmo não insira os valores, ainda assim ele está errado. Precisa remove-lo.

Comment: essa deu certo obrigado..

Comment: Se a resposta dele foi o que resolveu o seu problema, você deveria marcar a dele como correta clicando no sinal ✓ - Como já foi orientando anteriormente.

Answer (score 1):

Tente algo desta maneira já que você deseja somente cadastrar.

```
$cnpj = "000001";
$sth = $lokos->prepare("INSERT INTO CLENTES (CNPJ) VALUES (?)"); 
$sth->execute(array($cnpj));
```

Lembrando que sua variável `$lokos` deve ser a que efetua a conexão com o banco de dados, normalmente utiliza-se `$conn` algo do tipo.

Answer (score 0):

> Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string

Esse erro é causado pela linha `echo $sth;`, `$sth` não é uma variável escalar, para imprimir objetos ou arrays use as funções [print_r()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) ou [var_dump()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php).

O `insert` normalmente não retorna valor, nesse caso remova a linha

```
$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Para tratar e descobrir o erro na consulta, adicione um if no execute()

```
if($sth->execute() === false){
   print_r($sth->errorInfo);
}
```